# I want to run my Django project from a local branch. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: python, django, git, pycharm

I'm working on a project and I want to test a feature locally for which I created a local git branch. I want `python manage.py runserver` to run changes made in the feature branch but it still runs from the `master` branch.

It would be great if someone can explain why it does this as well.

Comment: use git checkout <new-feature-branch-name> ??

Comment: No, tried that doesn't work.

Comment: Probably because git saves stuff commit wise in the `.git` folder

Comment: Django shoudln't read anything from the `.git` folder. Make sure that you are actually changing branch and it's not aborted for things like having uncommitted changes. Also, I'd stop the `runserver` command while changing branch (Python caches compiled files).

Comment: @Martí I did that.
- Stopped the `runserver` properly.